# After reinstalling flutter, new android projects don't compile anymore

Tags: android, flutter

Old projects compile normally, but they take much longer than before.

New projects compile normally for windows and web, but they don't work on android.

Here is the log:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Dev\flutter_application_1\android\build.gradle' line: 13

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> Build completed with 1 failures.
   > org/jetbrains/kotlin/config/LanguageVersion

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1


Exited (1).
```

I tried deleting the android folder and reconstruct it with:

```
flutter create --platform android .
```

The error remains the same tho.
Flutter doctors says everything is fine:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.19.2, on Microsoft Windows [versÆo 10.0.19045.4046])
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio Community 2019 16.11.34)
[√] Android Studio (version 2023.1)
[√] VS Code (version 1.87.0)
[√] Connected device (4 available)
[√] Network resources

• No issues found!
```

I noticed the new build.gradle is smaller than usual:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I've run out of ideas, and couldn't find a similar issue around.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a temporary solution using some clues on this [post](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/45681#issuecomment-559098716).

Seems to be some kind of incompatibility with the gradle version used by flutter's new project template.

But still, for every new project I seem to have to change these configurations to be able to run:

- step 1: go to android/.gradle and delete the version folder i guess you have 7.6.3
- step 2: go to android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties open the properties file and change the distribution URL from https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6.3-all.zip to https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-all.zip